# Scala Set.contains doesn't give expected type mismatch error

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I'm new to Scala, and I'm struggling to understand why I sometimes don't get a type error when supplying the wrong argument to `Set.contains`

Here's a quick example using the REPL (2.9.1.final):

```
scala> val baz = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
baz: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)

scala> baz.values.toSet.contains("asdf")
res3: Boolean = false
```

Why didn't I get a type mismatch there?

If I assign `baz.values.toSet` to another `val`, and call `contains` on that, I *do* get type checking:

```
scala> val bling = baz.values.toSet
bling: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)

scala> bling.contains("asdf")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("asdf")
 required: Int
              bling.contains("asdf")
                             ^
```

Stupid mistake, language subtlety, or compiler bug?

Comment: Short answer: language subtlety (subtyping and type inference)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so `Set` is invariant in its type parameter and it works exactly like it should

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3) contains "Hi"
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("Hi")
 required: Int
              Set(1, 2, 3) contains "Hi"
                                    ^
```

But, like you say:

```
scala> Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3).values.toSet contains "Hi"
res1: Boolean = false
```

The only conclusion we can reasonably come to is that the type of the `Set` in question is *not* `Set[Int]`. What happens if we explicitly tell scala we want a `Set[Int]`? The same piece of code with an explicit type parameter works just fine (i.e. it does not compile):

```
scala> Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3).values.toSet[Int] contains "Hi"
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("Hi")
 required: Int
              Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3).values.toSet[Int] contains "Hi"
                                                                        ^
```

The issue is the **inferred type parameter** being passed to the `toSet` method. Scala is obviously taking the `contains "Hi"` into account and inferring the lub of `Int` and `String` (i.e. `Any`)

Comment: Are you saying that Scala is inferring from the ***subsequent usage*** of the set that the set's type parameter should be something broader, like `Any`?

Comment: Damn, beat me to it. +1 for you. Some further explanation is that when you call `baz.values.toSet.contains("asdf")`, it finds the closest type that satisfies the condition `[X >: Int]`, and it finds `X` is `Any`, meaning that the result of your `toSet` is a `Set[Any]`. Because of this, you should explicitly say what type you want the set to be, as oxbow mentioned.

Comment: Shouldn't you have explained that it is inferring the type of `Set` as `Any`?

Comment: @Daniel - isn't that what I just did?

Comment: @ChrisShain - this is the only conclusion we can reasonably come to

Comment: Ah- Scala's type inference is at the *whole statement* level, so another way to think about it is that it is trying to evaluate the statement `baz.values.toSet.contains("asdf")` into a value, and the only way to do that is if `toSet` is called with `Any` as a type parameter.

Comment: Note that `val x = Map(1->2,3->4).values.toSet; x contains "Hi"` gives the expected error.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have to say that this inferencing behaviour seems strange and unhelpful.  The type of `baz` was previously inferred, so I'd expect `baz.values` and `baz.values.toSet` to have definite types (no further inferencing required).  When you enter those expressions on their own, the types are as expected.  It seems odd that the presence of the `contains` call causes type inference to occur.  Perhaps it's just a gotcha to be aware of, but I'm interested to know whether the language designers consider this behaviour desirable (for the sake of other situations) or unfortunate.

Comment: I think the question should be: *what examples exist where this is a good thing?*

Comment: That's a good way of putting it, @oxbow_lakes.  I've accepted your answer, as it addresses my question as posed (it's not a stupid mistake on my part, or a compiler bug, but rather the expected behaviour of Scala).  But like you, I now really want to know how this behaviour is justified — "_what examples exist where this is a good thing?_"