# Why is `contains` on collections not requiring the correct type?

Tags: scala, scala-3

How come this compiles:

```scala
scala> val x: Vector[Int] = Vector(1,2,3)
val x: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> x.contains("hello")
val res4: Boolean = false

scala> x.contains(List(Map("anything" -> 3.14)))                                                 
val res5: Boolean = false
```

EDIT:

This is separate from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536731/scala-set-contains-doesnt-give-expected-type-mismatch-error) in which the element type of the collection is inferred (to `Any`) whereas here it is explicitly set (to `Int`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala Set.contains doesn't give expected type mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536731/scala-set-contains-doesnt-give-expected-type-mismatch-error)

Comment: Also take a look at this https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10831

Comment: @texasbruce your links don't seem to answer my question, since in both cases the element type of the collection is inferred (to `Any`), whereas here I explicitly set it to `Int`.

Comment: @thatotherguy as far as I know, Scala collections are quite separate from Java collections, except for `Array`.

Comment: @thatotherguy It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature [is](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.0.0/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html#contains-e1c) (in 3.0.0; I recommend always including the language/library version in such questions, and for Scala in particular)

```
def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean
```

This means that the argument type must be a supertype of `Int`, and `"hello"` is inferred to be `Any` which is indeed such a supertype.

The reason for the signature instead of maybe more expected

```
def contains(elem: A): Boolean
```

is that that signature wouldn't allow `Vector` and other collections to be covariant.

Specifically, if a `Vector[Int]` extends `Vector[Any]`, and you can call `contains(Any)` on a `Vector[Any]`, you must also be able to call it on a `Vector[Int]`.

Comment: Thanks - that seems like an unfortunate trade-off. Could this be improved by using extension methods?

Comment: I am not certain, but I think the reasoning in the last paragraph still holds even with extension methods and the `contains(A)` signature and Scala would happily infer it.

Comment: But at any rate you don't want extension methods here, because e.g. `Range` definitely should override the default implementation.

Comment: You can consider Cats' extension methods for that. They are typeclass based and invariant. In particular I mean `contains_` method of `Foldable`: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/ce76f665768ef85a7266a2911fa538be3a1ef6ab/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/foldable.scala#L66

Comment: Ah yes, if you also have an implicit parameter as in a typeclass, things change.